# How to make a thicker text shadow using css?

Tags: css

I want to achieve this text style like so:

[image]

I want to wrap the text with color white like the image above I tried using

```
   text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
```

but it turns out that the shadow will get blurry. Is there any chance that I can do it using css (if so how)? or should I just convert it into image?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simulate it, doing like this:

**CSS**

```css
span {
  text-shadow: 
    2px 2px 0px #fff, 
    -2px -2px 0px #fff, 
    2px -2px 0px #fff, 
    -2px 2px 0px #fff;
}
```

#### Demo

```css
body { background: #aaa; }

h1 {
  text-shadow: 
    2px 2px 0px #fff, 
    -2px -2px 0px #fff, 
    2px -2px 0px #fff, 
    -2px 2px 0px #fff;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>800-555-1234</h1>
```

Comment: That is hardly the same stroke width demonstrated in the original post, and is not realistically scalable.

Comment: Not quite accurate with some other font but I think it'll do the trick, so I'm accepting this as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The effect you seek is called **stroke** and sadly not possible (yet) with CSS in a [cross browser compatible way](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke).

Faking it with shadows will not work for a stroke thicker than 1 or 2 pixels, or require a ton of layered shadows, slowing down rendering. Other faking techniques [are possible but not quite fantastic](https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/).

For now the best bet remains to use images for the rare occasions where this is useful.

Comment: SVG offers `stroke` and can incorporate selectable, linkable, text which might be a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this today and at least for Webkit browsers, there's a better solution. You can follow [this old article](https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/) using the code

```
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
```

and also try using text shadows with it. It worked well for me after some pixel-pushing. I have some bigger letters, so I ended up using a text shadow like this

```
text-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #010000, 2px 3px 0px #010000, 4px 5px 0px #010000, 4px 6px 0px #010000;
```

I hope that helps!